# Tiling window management - triple tiling

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, window, window-manager, tiling

I use window tiling with keyboard shortcuts a lot on my Ubuntu. However, back in the days when I was using an XP OS at work, I found a great tiling manager software called Splitview. The difference which Splitview creates is when you press -let's say- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> the window spans the right half of the screen. But, if you repeat the same key combination, this time, the window spans right 1/3 of the screen [image: As seen here in triple (vertical) tiling].

So, I could practically tile 3 windows vertically which was obviously increasing my productivity. Since then (namely since Ubuntu 8.04) I am searching for such a feature time to time. Do you know of any similar extensions? To be honest, I don't want to try new X managers.

Comment: You can span 1/2 of screen by super+left/right or move window to left/right with mouse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `compizconfig-manager`, the "grid" plugin has a property called "Cycle through multiple sizes" under "Resize Actions" tab. I checked it and it works as I expected.

[This video helped me figure it out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQVkY6zMxCg)

Comment: Now you must mark your answer as the accepted answer to your question. Click the checkmark to the left of the text. This will tell other users that there is wisdom here.

Comment: I am warned that I can accept it as an answer tomorrow. After then I will, thanks.

Comment: Ah yes. Forgt about that. By the way. There is no need to feel terrible. That you continued to work on the problem after posting is taken well by most here.